# Are grand central dispatch blocks thread safe?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I have a class, called TestView with an instance variable called 'loader' of type Loader.  I created a method on TestView to instantiate the loader; and then start loading something 2 seconds later.

That method looks like this:

```
-(void) createLoaderAndStartLoadingTwoSecondsLater{
    loader =  Loader();
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        printf("DISPATCHING AFTER %i seconds", i);
        loader->load(*urlRequest);
    });
}
```

Elsewhere, there is a dealloc method:

```
-(void) dealloc
{
    delete loader; 
}
```

It is possible for dealloc to get called before the 2 second timer elapses.  In that case, I would like it if the dispatch_after block never executed.

EDIT:
I would like to do this:

```
  dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        printf("DISPATCHING AFTER %i seconds", i);
        if ( !hasBeenDeleted( loader ) ){
             loader->load(*urlRequest);
        }
    });
```

But I am worried about two things:

- I don't know how I would implement a has been deleted function
- I worry that hasBeenDeleted would return false, and then the loader would get deleted on another thread.

So I would really like to do this:

```
  dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        printf("DISPATCHING AFTER %i seconds", i);
        lockTheOtherThreads();
        if ( !hasBeenDeleted( loader ) ){
             loader->load(*urlRequest);
        }
        unlockTheOtherThreads();
    });
```

But I also don't know how to implement lockTheOtherThreads()

Comment: Your last paragraph is very confused. What do you mean by "guaranteed to execute without switching threads"? In any case, that doesn't correspond to any definition of "thread safe" that I can think of. And what would you check for null and how do you think that would allow you to "be done with it"?

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't realize how unclear that was when I wrote it. I edited the question to hopefully clear things up.

Comment: You shouldn't think in terms of a has-been-deleted test. Instead you should ensure that it **won't** be deleted by maintaining a strong reference. If you want to cancel the load, you should do that another way. For example, use `NSTimer` on a known run loop (i.e. the main run loop) and invalidate it to cancel it. Or, similarly, use `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` and then `+cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:` to cancel it. In any case, the loader should be retained so long as the delayed code is pending. Arrange it so canceling it is what releases it.

Comment: Aha, thank you. Really all I wanted to do was cancel the dispatch_async.  I don't use iOS so often, and I forget that  `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` and `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object` existed.  That should solve this.

Answer (score 3):

assuming your have this

```
@implementation MyClass {
    Loader *loader;
} 

-(void)createLoaderAndStartLoadingTwoSecondsLater{
    loader = new Loader();
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        printf("DISPATCHING AFTER %i seconds", i);
        loader->load(*urlRequest);
        //self->loader->load(*self->urlRequest);
    });
}
```

The dispatch block you created will hold a strong reference to `self`, which means `dealloc` will not get called before the block executed.

Also use `unique_ptr` so you don't need to call delete. Or `shared_ptr` with `atomic_load` if loader can be accessed by multiple threads.

```
@implementation MyClass {
    std::unique_ptr<Loader> loader;
} 

-(void)createLoaderAndStartLoadingTwoSecondsLater{
    loader.reset(new Loader()); // will delete previous loader if it exist
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        printf("DISPATCHING AFTER %i seconds", i);
        loader->load(*urlRequest);
    });
}

// you don't need dealloc anymore
```

---

Update:

You can capture the a weak reference to `self` in the block to avoid it extending the lifetime of `self`

```
-(void)createLoaderAndStartLoadingTwoSecondsLater{
    loader.reset(new Loader()); // will delete previous loader if it exist
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self; // a weak reference to self
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
        printf("DISPATCHING AFTER %i seconds", i);
        if (strongSelf) { // if still alive
            strongSelf->loader->load(*urlRequest);
        } // else it is deallocated
    });
}
```

Comment: Ok, this makes sense.  I will have to read up on shared_ptr and atomic_load.  I edited the question to maybe clarify it a little, I guess I really want to have some way of telling the block that it no longer needs to do anything.  I guess I could write some MyClass#cancelTheBlock method, and have it set some variable on the class.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite unclear what you are actually trying to do. And things aren't just "thread-safe", you need to say what you want to do.

Once dealloc is called, the object in question will be gone when dealloc returns. Doesn't matter if someone else tried to retain it. And it seems you are mixing up Objective-C and C++. When delete is called in C++, the object is gone.

I suggest you read up on weak pointers in Objective-C and stay away from C++.

Comment: It's not a good language for a poster who seems confused enough already.

Comment: many people are confused by C++, you can't just tell them stay away from it.